# Why do we use mice in labs?

Tags: human-biology, animal-models, research-process

Why do we use mice in labs for experiments targeting humans ? Are they near humans biologically speaking ?

Comment: Interesting question in principle, but what research have you so far done to find an answer? It's a question that is addressed pretty much in every introductory textbook. In short, mice are often not good models for humans, that is indeed a big problem. But often it is not ethical or even possible to do experiments with humans (you're not allowed to insert things into peoples' brains, for example, or kill and dissect them), so animals are the only option. And animals can be bred to have specific characteristics.

Comment: Maybe start by skimming Wikipedia's page on [Model Organisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_organism#Selection), then edit your question with any specifics that remain unanswered?  Jamesqf covered a few pragmatic reasons, but there are a lot of other ones

Answer (score 1):

Quite apart from ethical issues*, there's simple practicality.  Mice are about the smallest & fastest-reproducing mammal.  Mouse generation time is about 10 weeks, vs maybe 15 years for humans, and have average litter sizes of 6-8, vs a bit over one for humans.  Life span is correspondingly shorter, so experiments can be done over the entire life, or for multiple generations.  Mice occupy a lot less space, and are a lot cheaper to feed, which is a consideration when applying for research grants.

(And in the early days of research, one could just catch wild mice, instead of having to ship in some exotic species such as monkeys.)

*Which not everyone subscribes to. We do have ample historical evidence of humans used as lab animals.

Comment: you explain why this is a good model organism, but not why it is used in research targeting humans.

Comment: @Hachiloni: I DO explain that.  Because they're cheap, obviously :-)

Comment: algae are also cheap but you can study them to understand humans. Why mice are suitable for that?

Comment: @Hachiloni: Mice are mammals, algae are plants.  The biology is considerably different :-)  It's a matter of optimizing cost vs relevance of results.  You'll find that a lot of research IS done with plants, or with fruit flies, because they're even cheaper than mice, and the biology being studied is similar enough.  Likewise other research needs to be done with different, more expensive, animals such as primates, and sometimes (as with vaccines) human testing needs to be done.

Comment: Comparing mice and macaques (as human models and practicability for labs) would be interesting.